# Using Wget / shell to download a file from outside of the web root

Tags: shell, apache-http-server, wget

I am trying to download the httpd.conf file so that I can edit my Apache configuration.

I can get access to the directory it is in via the shell (I have root access), but all of the examples on how to use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to download a file from the web server use a URL, and the file is not in the web root (`public_html`); it's in `root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

I'm in that directory, and I tried just

```
wget httpd.cong
```

but it complains.

What's the correct Wget syntax?

Comment: There is no correct syntax, that is not how a webserver works; the server files, including the config file are *separate* from the document files which are served. You cannot access it from the HTTP URL, you have to access it via the server address that you use to open a shell, except that instead of using a shell to access the server address, you use `wget`. Unlike accessing a webserver, you have to also provide your username and password to `wget` just as you would when logging in. Dylan gave a good example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Wget man usage:

```
 wget [option]... [URL]...
```

where [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) resemble

```
 http://host[:port]/directory/file
 ftp://host[:port]/directory/file
```

So in your case,

```
 wget --user=user --password='pass' ftp://host[:port]/directory/relative/to/user
```

You could use `scp`:

```
 scp user@example.com:/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /some/local/directory
```

Or even FTP. Recommended clients are [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) or [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY). If you just need to edit the file, there is no need to download it. Look up file editors such as [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) or [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: For the sake of your learning I'm going to point out a problem regarding your question. This isn't so much an Apache issue as it is simply file editing. Apache is your HTTP server which provides access to the webpages and files you specify. Altering your configuration however, is a filesystem question

Comment: Thanks for the advice and lessons Dylan :) I use Filezilla to access my ftp currently, but it's limited to move one directory above the webroot, is this a permissions issue on the FTP user I am using? I've never used FTP to access root directories.

With wget, if I'm already loggedinto shell (PuTTy) as root, do I still need to specify user and password in the query?

Comment: I would use scp from my local machine then. Using `wget` while logged into your server would only pull files onto that server.

Comment: Use the user you normally would for ssh. I would be weary changing permissions for your FTP user. Access is not something that should be thrown around lightly.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to edit the `httpd.conf` file, and have access to it via shell, you can simply edit it using a shell editor such as `nano` rather than downloading it. Simply run :

```
cd /directory/containing/the/file
nano httpd.conf
```

Make you modifications, then save by pressing `Ctrl`+`x`, if you use `nano`.

Comment: The file is not stored locally, it is stored on the web-server.

Comment: @Synetech yes, and as long as there is shell access to the file (which is the case here), `nano` can be run on the web-server to edit it.

Comment: But not with the syntax you provided. He’ll have to use the server’s address with username and password as Dylan demonstrated.

Comment: @Synetech not if he opened a shell on the server. Based on the question, it really looks like he did.

Comment: True, but I didn’t get that impression. He’s asking how to *download* the file with `wget` to edit it, not how to edit it while logged into the server. I see what you mean now, you are talking about running `nano` in the shell while logged in (I thought you meant running it locally). Yes, that makes sense.